# Hexagonal seret vizhnitz yarmulke

Tags: product-recommendation, kippa-yarmulka

Does anyone know where to find the hexagonal seret vizhnitz yarmulkes? They are impossible to find.
And to get it from Israel especially is impossible and super expensive, is there maybe any place to find them in new York

Comment: The Vizhnitz have a community in Kaser, New York. Call there.

Comment: see also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/117978/170