# Does Seret Vizhnitz have a particular kittle style and where can I buy?

Tags: minhag, product-recommendation, yom-kippur

My family are affiliated with Seret Vizhnitz Haifa. I have always wanted to find out what particular kittle style they wear on YK, or if it is a generic one. When I got married, a friend gave me his old generic one and so I just used that but now it is worn out, so I am using the opportunity to get the one I always wanted.

Comment: Why don't you take your old one to a Judaica store and ask the for the same type?

Comment: He doesn't want the same (generic) one, he wants an authentic S. V. one

Comment: see also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/104540/170